# What happens to used arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, performance

Can anyone please tell me what happens to used arrays middle in the program? Can i manually free memory or java itself frees the allocated memory.

Comment: Arrays are just objects and get handled the same way (AFAIK with some special treatment for huge arrays, but that doesn't change the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM has a Garbage Collector, which will free those. You don't need do it manually.

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory,
>   identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting
>   the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means
>   that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that
>   object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer
>   referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an
>   unreferenced object can be reclaimed.
>
> In a programming language like C, allocating and deallocating memory
>   is a manual process. In Java, process of deallocating memory is
>   handled automatically by the garbage collector. The basic process can
>   be described as follows.

For more details, check [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)